# Running a console from Progarm.cs in a winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, console

Why when I try to open a console from a winform application I get
the exception

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeMultiLevelDS
{
   static class Program
   {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Console.ReadKey();
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         Application.Run(new Form1());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not a Console application, so... Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: What makes an application a console application? I want to combine both winforms and console.

Comment: The Project template (`<OutputType>`, plus a number of other things). Are you trying to build a Console app or a WinForms app? Or do want to add a Console to a WinForms executable? Or do you want to open a Form from a Console app?

Comment: Add a console to a WinForms app for interaction .In your words " to add a Console to a WinForms executable".

Comment: Yes, but to what end? A WinForm app is already *interactive*. What is this Console for? You need to add some specifics to your question.

Comment: My question is why I get the Exception? not the trivial answer " it's not a Console application" but where in the code do you see if its not a console application.

Answer (score 1):

Change project Output Type.

ProjectName > RightClick > Properties > Output Type

Choose Console application.